# Joins with Dapper return null

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I have the following classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string EventText { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public string ColorIdentifier { get; set; }
    public int Week { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to get all the users and their events with Dapper like this:

```
var sql = "SELECT u.Id, e.UserId, e.EventText FROM cpc.PLANNING_TOOL_USERS u  LEFT JOIN cpc.PLANNING_TOOL_EVENTS e ON u.Id=e.UserId";
var result = SqlMapper.Query<User, Event, User>(connection, sql, (u, e) =>
{
   if (u.Events == null)
      u.Events = new List<Event>();
   u.Events.Add(e);

   return u;

}, splitOn: "Id, UserId");
```

The Id for the user is returned back, but the list of events is not populated. I have looked at many examples here on Stack Overflow regarding this, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: do you get the right data if you run the sql directly on the database?

Comment: @BugFinder: Yes :)

Comment: thats a good start at least.

Comment: Try change the spliton to just userid. See if it works.

Answer (score 1):

To omit the situation that SQL returns no data I have just mocked two user rows with SQL `union`.
`User` with `Id=1` and one `Event`, and `User` with `Id=2` and two `Event`s.

`SqlMapper.Query` returns flat results that are best for 1 to 1 relation. You have one user to many events relation, so some helper storage needed to maintain that relation as a mapping thru the results. I have used .NET dictionary for that.

My code sample below:

```
        // introducing temporary storage
        var usersDictionary = new Dictionary<int, User>();

        var sql = @"SELECT 1 Id, 1 UserId, 'EventText1' EventText
                  union SELECT 2 Id, 2 UserId, 'EventText2'  EventText
                  union SELECT 2 Id, 2 UserId, 'Another EventText2' EventText";
        var result = SqlMapper.Query<User, Event, User>(connection, sql, (u, e) =>
        {
            if (!usersDictionary.ContainsKey(u.Id))
                usersDictionary.Add(u.Id, u);
            var cachedUser = usersDictionary[u.Id];

            if (cachedUser.Events == null)
                cachedUser.Events = new List<Event>();
            cachedUser.Events.Add(e);

            return cachedUser;

        }, splitOn: "UserId");

        // we are not really interested in `result` here
        // we are more interested in the `usersDictionary`

        var users = usersDictionary.Values.AsList();
        Assert.AreEqual(2, users.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, users[0].Id);
        CollectionAssert.IsNotEmpty(users[0].Events);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, users[0].Events.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("EventText1", users[0].Events[0].EventText);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, users[1].Events.Count);
```

I hope that helped you solving your mapping issue and events being `null`.

Comment: So I can't use a JOIN?

Comment: You absolutely can. My `union`s are just to join three rows together. You can think of that my query as a query with the `join`s that returns three rows. I did not have your database schema to write the query with the joins, so mimicked that with union.